# openSSL SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations fails

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

On Linux Debian, consider the following C/C++ snippet:

```
TRACE << "TLSv1_2_client_method() started";
// Set up a SSL_CTX object, which will tell our BIO object how to do its work
const SSL_METHOD* method = TLSv1_2_client_method();
TRACE << "TLSv1_2_client_method() ended";

if (method == NULL) {
    ERROR << "SSL_METHOD is null";
    return false;
}

TRACE << "SSL_CTX_new() started";
SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
TRACE << "SSL_CTX_new() ended";
if (ctx == NULL) {
    ERROR << "SSL CTX is null";
    return false;
}

TRACE << "SSL_CTX_set_verify() started";
SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);
TRACE << "SSL_CTX_set_verify() ended";

TRACE << "SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth() started";
SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(ctx, 4);
TRACE << "SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth() ended";

TRACE << "SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations() started";
if (!SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, CA_CERTIFICATE_FILE, NULL)) {
    ERROR << "SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations failed";
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    return false;
}
TRACE << "SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations() ended";
```

This function was running for literally ages, but some day ago *SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations* retured 0 thus the function returned.

Now from openSSL's [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.html): it can only return 0 when "The operation failed because CAfile and CApath are NULL or the processing at one of the locations specified failed. Check the error stack to find out the reason."

Let's take this sentence into parts:

- (CAfile and CApath are null)? **NO**. They are hard-coded defines in the code.
- or the processing at one of the locations specified failed? **Maybe**.

What I'm interested in is the *Maybe* above.

This function ran periodically, in every minute. Log file was full of this error message "SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations failed". So indeed, "the processing at one of the locations specified failed" could happen.

BUT! After killing the application, and then restarting it, the function is working again as intended without any error.

What can cause SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations to fail in this case? Obviously not something that relates to the verification itself. (because it fixed itself as soon as I restarted the app)

Comment: have you tried getting the error description? There is a specific way to get more Information from openssl. Unfortunately I do not have it at hand, I will add it later.

Comment: SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations expects the certificates in PEM format, it will fail otherwise,also you need to make sure the file and path  exists on the system where the code is run

Comment: @ArneFischer: unfortunately deeper error displaying was not part of the code. I'll add it for sure, just wanted to know if something can be extracted from the above info. Thanks though.

Comment: @Pras: you don't get the point I think. File is in PEM. It exists. Code was running for ages, but at some time stopped. Then after kill and rerun (the app, not the computer) it works correctly again. The file was not touched between stopping and starting.

Comment: @Daniel ok makes sense. Do you have a way to reproduce the issue? It is strange that it started to work after a restart. Maybe something to do with initialisation orders?

Comment: @ArneFischer: no, unfortunately this issue is not reproducable but I don't want to pass by. What do you mean by initialisation?